# Batch - How to get variables outside of for-loop block?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following properties file

```
jmx.connector.ip=127.0.0.1
jmx.connector.port=12345
```

which I want to read and parse the key-value pairs

```
@ECHO OFF

set FILE=file.properties

REM initialize???
set JMXPORT=0
set JMXHOST=0

REM set their value???
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (%FILE%) do (
    if "%%i"=="jmx.connector.port" JMXPORT=%%j
    if "%%i"=="jmx.connector.ip" JMXHOST=%%j
)

REM can't use their value
echo %JMXHOST%
echo %JMXPORT%
```

This doesn't work. I want to set the values for `JMXPORT` and `JMXHOST` within the for-loop and use them outside the loop. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the appropriate `set` call in your loop. Change the loop to:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (%FILE%) do (
    if "%%i"=="jmx.connector.port" set JMXPORT=%%j
    if "%%i"=="jmx.connector.ip" set JMXHOST=%%j
)
```

It should then work (at least it did for me on Windows 7).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `set` to the `if` statements, like this:

```
if "%%i"=="jmx.connector.port" set JMXPORT=%%j
if "%%i"=="jmx.connector.ip" set JMXHOST=%%j
```

If that doesn't work, then you need to enable delayed expansion at the beginning of your batch file and use `!` instead of `%` for your variables, like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set FILE=file.properties

REM initialize???
set JMXPORT=0
set JMXHOST=0

REM set their value???
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (%FILE%) do (
    if "%%i"=="jmx.connector.port" set JMXPORT=%%j
    if "%%i"=="jmx.connector.ip" set JMXHOST=%%j
)

REM can't use their value
echo !JMXHOST!
echo !JMXPORT!

setlocal
```

Comment: You typed the wrong for loop variable...  I'll fix my answer.  You are using `%%i` in the for loop, but `%%j` in the `set` statement.

Comment: No, `%%i` is supposed to get the key of the property as the first token from the `for` loop, `%%j` is supposed to get the value of the property.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Each token is assigned to a character after the one declared in the for loop. In my example, first token goes to %%i, second goes to %%j, if there was a third it would go to %%k, and so on. See the [for loop description](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)